# React JS: no answer from Sinatra server with fetch call

Tags: javascript, ruby, reactjs, sinatra, fetch-api

I am quite new to Sinatra and React JS, therefore I just wanted to make an GET call from my React website on a Sinatra server to display a plain text.

Sinatra Server:

```
require 'sinatra'

set :root, 'lib/app'

before do
  response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = 'http://localhost:8080'
  response.headers['Accept'] = 'gridoperator'
  response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'gridoperator'
end

get '/gridoperator' do
  'Hello root gridoperator'
end
```

React JS:

```
var Gridoperator_div = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function(){
    return({
      call_name: 'initial'
    });
  },

  componentDidMount: function(){

    fetch('http://localhost:4567/gridoperator', {
      method: 'get'
    }).then(response => response.text())
    .then(
        function(text){
          this.setState({
            call_name: text
          })
    });

  },

  componentWillUnmount: function(){
  },

  render: function() {
    return(
        <h1>Hello {this.state.call_name}!</h1>
    )
  }

});

ReactDOM.render(<Gridoperator_div/>, document.getElementById('gridoperator'));
```

The Sinatra Server is tested with REST and should work.

Unfortunately if I want to connect with my React website, the only thing I can read is this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPvm4.jpg)

In the log the connection of my React website is recognized:

```
::1 - - [10/Feb/2017:21:28:00 +0100] "GET /gridoperator HTTP/1.1" 200 23 0.0000
::1 - - [10/Feb/2017:21:28:00 Mitteleuropõische Zeit] "GET /gridoperator HTTP/1.1" 200 23
http://localhost:8080/ -> /gridoperator
```

I really hope someone can help me, therefore Thanks in Advance!

Fossa

**Edit**

I forgot about something, if I start my website, it compiles with warnings:

```
WARNING in ./~/encoding/lib/iconv-loader.js
Critical dependencies:
9:12-34 the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./~/encoding/lib/iconv-loader.js 9:12-34
webpack: Compiled with warnings.
```

Comment: have you looked in the browser javascript console for errors?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing more it's hard to say what the exact problem is, but if I had to guess, I'd say it's probably something with the CORS preflight since you're getting so little back. That also explains why static content can be loaded.

It looks like you're hand-rolling your own logic for this with `response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = 'http://localhost:8080'`. You're not setting all the CORS headers which may be why the requests aren't going through. See [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) for more.

Hand-rolling this sort of logic is almost always a bad idea. Check out https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors or https://github.com/britg/sinatra-cross_origin. I recommend the former. It's easy to configure and once you have it set up, you can more or less forget about it.